# AJAX не понимаю как работает function(data) не возвращает ответ

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

не понимаю почему во втором случае код работает а в первом не возвращает из php форму, (в коде не работает закомментированная часть)

```js
$("document").ready(function() {

    $("#naw_otprav").on("submit", function() {

        let dataForm = $(this).serialize()
        /* отправляем AJAX запрос */
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: '/naw_dobaw',
            method: 'get',
            dataType: 'html',
            data: dataForm,
            success: function(data){
                console.log(data)
            },
        });

        // let formDatas = new FormData(naw_otprav);
        // let formDatas = { asdasd: "asdasd"};
        // /* отправляем AJAX запрос */
        // $.ajax({
        //     type: "get",
        //     url: 'naw_dobaw',
        //     contentType: false,
        //     processData: false,
        //     data: formDatas,
        //     success: function(data){
        //         console.log(data);
        //     },
        // });

    })
})
```

```html
<?php

echo "Привет";

print_r($_GET);
```

[image: не работает форма вывода]

Comment: url: '/naw_dobaw',  у вас должно быть так naw_dobaw.php

Comment: Почитай как использовать `new FormData`. https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects

Comment: Почитал, помогло проблему решил проблема была в другой части кода.